# Android emulator won't run on Windows 7 32-bit

Tags: android, eclipse, windows-7, android-emulator, emulation

I am using Eclipse on a HP Mini laptop to develop Android applications. When I run the Android emulator, it shows the screen with the text ANDROID, however it doesn't progress further than that. I then get an error saying "emulator-x86.exe has stopped working". I'm not sure what the issue causing this error is. I tried installing Intel HAX, but it won't work because my computer is 32-bit.

I understand that this may not be the best place to look for an answer, but I couldn't find a solution searching Google or looking at other StackOverflow questions. I also realise that this question may be vague, so if you need any information in order to answer the question, please ask for it in the comments.

Comment: Please check the memory allocated for your AVD. keep it not more than 512MB.

Comment: I set it at 512MB, 128MB and 64MB. I still get the same error

Comment: Can you post your AVD configuration here? Also HAXM is available for Windows 32 bit. Check here for download https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager

Comment: When I try to setup HAXM I get the error "This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x). HAXM cannot be installed. "

Comment: Enable Virtualization technology on your BIOS and try again

Comment: My computer doesn't support virtualization technology. I used Intel Processor Identification Utility to check